# Laravel, Add conditionable on every object

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any chance to having `->when()` or `->unless()` on any kind of objects in laravel?
I mean something that acts like following:

```php
$object = wrap($object)->when($condition===true,function($object){
   $object->changeSomething();
   return $object;
});/....
```

Comment: How would this be different than enclosing it in an if-statement? Seems like it would be less complicated.

Comment: There's no difference, I just wanted to know! @msmahon

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Only if the object is convertible to a collection class you can use when() and unless(). Not sure if that would answer your question.  `collect($object)->when()`
Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-when